# How do I map dispatch to props within a recursively nested component using React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am attempting to make an application that displays a family tree to React using Redux. Each person is displayed in a box with lines leading to their parents. I want to have a feature where if you click on a person's 'card' you see a popup that displays further biographical information. The trouble I am having is about mapping the dispatch action within any  component further down the tree than the root level person. It works as expected when I click on "John" at the top, but any of his ancestors and it breaks. Hopefully, I'm just missing something obvious!

[image: Here is the family tree with no bio card]

[image: This is the desired result ( with proper information ) upon clicking a family member]

[image: Here is the error message that I receive]

Here are the components:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getFamily} from '../redux/family.actions'
import "./Family.css";
import Person from './Person';

class Family extends Component {
    render() {
        const {rootPerson} = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="family family-container">
                <ul>
                    <Person key={rootPerson.id} info={rootPerson}/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    rootPerson: state.family.allFamilyMembers[0]
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getFamilyFromStore: () => dispatch(getFamily())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Family);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import {selectPerson} from '../redux/family.actions'

import "./Person.css";

const Person = props => (
    <li className="oc-hierarchy" onClick={() => props.selectPerson(props.info)}>
        <div className="card card-body oc-node">
            <h1>{props.info.name}</h1>
        </div>

        {props.info && props.info.parents && props.info.parents.length > 0 && (
                <ul>
                    {props.info.parents.map(child => (
                        <Person info={child} />
                        ))}
                </ul>
            )} 
    </li>
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    selectPerson: (person) => dispatch(selectPerson(person))
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Person);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

import './App.css';

import Family from './components/Family';
import PersonBio from './components/PersonBio';

function App({selectedPerson}) {

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Family />
        {selectedPerson == null ? null : <PersonBio />}
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    selectedPerson: state.family.selectedPerson
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (App);
```

```
export const selectPerson = (person) => ({
    type: 'SELECT_PERSON',
    payload: person
})
```

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    allFamilyMembers: [
        {
            id:0,
            name: 'John',
            parents: [
                {
                    id:1,
                    name: 'Bill',
                    parents: [
                        {
                            id:3,
                            name: 'Bob',
                            parents: [
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            id:4,
                            name: 'Barb',
                            parents: [
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id:2,
                    name: 'Mary',
                    parents: [
                        {
                            id:5,
                            name: 'Matt',
                            parents: [
                                {
                                    id:7,
                                    name: 'Mark',
                                    parents: [
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    id:8,
                                    name: 'Ruth',
                                    parents: [
                                    ]
                                },
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            id:6,
                            name: 'Marge',
                            parents: [
                            ]
                        },
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    selectedPerson: null
}

const familyReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_FAMILY':
            return state;
        case 'SELECT_PERSON':
            return {
                ...state,
                selectedPerson: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default familyReducer;
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `{props.info.parents.map(child => <Person info={child} selectPerson={props.selectPerson} />)}`

Comment: This solved my issue!  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't know the fundamental of ReactJS, you never passed the `selectPerson` function to the `Person` component, pay attention to this part of your code:

```js
<Person key={rootPerson.id} info={rootPerson}/>
```

You should pass the `selectPerson` to this line. otherwise, you got it as `undefined` inside the `Person` component

```js
<Person key={rootPerson.id} info={rootPerson} selectPersion={() => {}} />
```

Now the `selectPerson` is declared and you got a `noOp` function inside your `Person` component instead of getting `undefined`. this is cause of your issue.